# Bulk moving of posts

Tags: discussion, migration

I am wondering if Stack Overflow should not be cleaned up. Since there are now so many Stack Exchange sites. Can we not based on certain tags move posts from Stack Overflow to the appropriate sub Stack Exchange site. Like all Linux/Unix/AIX/..posts to the https://unix.stackexchange.com/?

I mean these sites are created to keep post on similar topics together so makes sense to actually make sure users learn to go to appropriate sub domain to get info and ask questions.

I am sure some posts will be easy to move, and a few will be harder, but nothing is impossible :-)

Comment: I see the question is severely disliked :D Remove it if you so wish

Comment: Keep the question because other people (like me) might have the same idea. But now I know why it's not practical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

This has been tried in the past and found not to work. There are several reasons for this:

1. The questions aren't really suitable for the target site - low quality etc.
2. For old questions with lots of votes this would cause a distortion in the reputation of users on the target site, giving people privileges they haven't really earned. If they're not active on the target site this can lead to problems. This is why questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.
3. There's no point in migrating questions with accepted answers. The OP isn't going to get any benefit from the move.
4. The posts might not actually be off topic on Stack Overflow. There is some overlap between sites.

There's no issue migrating **high quality** [new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890/165773), so vote/flag for those to be moved - as long as they are actually off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might want to mention the 60 day limit for migration.

Comment: @MadScientist - the 60 day limit was introduced because of point 2.

Comment: I find the whole idea of OFF TOPIC for Stack Overflow very strange. There are questions asked there that seems much better fit on sub sites, but they are allowed. Then other questions which seem to belong in either sites are marked as off topic. I think at least for Stack Overflow the OFF TOPIC argument is very subjective.

Comment: @AquaAlex - there's a separate discussion about whether "off topic" is the right phrase to be using in cases like this as it does cause confusion. "Out of scope" (for example) might be better.

Comment: Maybe in future there may be a way to link questions to a site then? So you can see questions with same tag irrespective of whether they are on Stack Overflow or the current Sub domain? One Destination, many paths

Comment: I love the argument of reputation/points. Is providing a good answer or assisting people with a issue not reward enough? :-D  And if someone answered a programming question on stackoverflow or on programming sub site what does it matter he has contributed to the StackExchange site and has been verified as a StackExchange "expert" . I would even have just given people points for StackExchange irrespective of which sub domain they posted on. But that is just me :D

Comment: If helping people with an issue was enough of a reward, ~90% percent of SO's problems wouldn't have existed in the first place.

Comment: @Yannis Unfortunately you are right. But we can always dream of an Utopia ;-)