# How can SO community decide a bulk migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

We should accept that some tags on Stack Overflow mostly have off-topic questions. Lots of users know that, but nobody takes action (flags don't help as well). If we don't do anything, more off-topic questions will appear. After some point users (like me) also hesitate to flag these questions, because there are many of them.

Let's come to my case. I mostly deal with digital design questions on both Stack Overflow and [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com). I see that there are many off-topic questions on SO, however I couldn't get a strong confirmation for that until now.

[Is digital design on-topic without HDL code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354015/is-digital-design-on-topic-without-hdl-code)

The best thing would be migrating off-topic questions to Electronics SE. As you may know, there are only 5 SE sites for the migration flag by implementation. Moderator intervention flag may also be used, but it's a little bit useless to be honest.

I follow a bunch of tags related to digital design and there are [9.3k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synthesis+or+system-verilog+or+verilog+or+vhdl+or+xilinx-ise+or+rtl+or+fpga+or+xilinx+or+hdl+or+asic+or+vivado+or+altera+or+quartus-ii+or+digital-logic+or+modelsim+or+yosys+or+myhdl+or+vlsi) for now. I would review all these questions and flag the off-topic ones, but my flag will not be enough to migrate them. The questions have only 20 views at average, so it's a little bit hard to get 5 flags.

I also think that flagging many questions (I guess hundreds) for moderator intervention is not a good thing for the moderators. The community should handle it, but how? Is it possible to arrange a review event or something like the [MSO-MSE split](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split)? What would be the decision process?

P.S. I'm not talking about migrating tags completely (e.g. [Bulk moving of posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269946/bulk-moving-of-posts)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can't.

Migrating a single, recent question is something that's ok to do on occasion for *good questions* that are just on the wrong site.

Mass migrating a whole bunch of questions, most of which are old and stale, is absolutely out of the question. Aside from the fact that we forbid moderators from migrating questions more than 60 days old, dumping a *ton* of questions onto another site all at once is a good way to irritate all the members of that site by flooding their homepage with stuff that probably won't ever get further feedback.

If you run across a new off-topic question right after it got posted, feel free to direct the user to the correct site in the comments. Seriously, it's far more effective to just have them delete their off-topic question here and re-post it there than waiting for a moderator to get around to your flag and *maybe* take action if they feel comfortable with the migration (they probably won't).

Any questions older than that, just vote to close them as off-topic and be done with it. You can still point them in the right direction in a custom off-topic reason.