# Do VHDL/Verilog questions belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

According to Stack Overflow [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it is intended for programmers and questions about software design and development. For electronic design related questions we have this site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

By what seems to me as a historical mistake, a few tags related to electronic design were created on Stack Overflow e.g. [vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl), [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog), [fpga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpga).

[VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) and [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) are not programming languages, but hardware description languages ([HDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language)) and don't belong to software development realm. These languages are used by electronic engineers and the
product of processing HDL code is conceptually different from product of programming language code. The former produce net-lists while the later produce CPU instructions (conceptually).

Thus, it seems to me the right thing is to make these tags deprecated/locked and if possible relocate all the existing questions to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

What do you think?

Comment: I certainly *felt like* I was "programming" when using VHDL in university. And this was after I'd been exposed to multiple "traditional" programming languages. Stack Overflow also allows questions about CSS, Excel macros, ...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I did write VHDL myself too few years back. But still, it's conceptually not the same. Statistically speaking, these questions would be relevant for 5% of software engineers? While most electronic engineers would feel related. So it probably belongs more for the second site in my opinion. Unless it's a hybrid question related to software as well.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Hardware Description Language questions: Stack Overflow or Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85757/241919)

Comment: "*relocate all the existing questions to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/*" that is impossible to be done by mods, and is [unlikely to be done by staff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354553/2821954).

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't agree with the author of that question. He claims that HDL questions are "on-topic by consensus". But I do think that HDL isn't a programming language but an electronic design languages. So they don't answer the "on-topic" part.

Comment: Hardware Descriptor Languages are for programming logic circuits, it's generally used by computer engineers, not electrical engineers (sort of). Generally an EE is usually more focused on the circuit board that will host the chip, whereas the engineers designing the chips in an HDL are concerned with logic, and not whether there traces are going to have too much capacitance. From what I've seen of Electronics SE, I'd say HDL's are actually a pretty bad fit over there.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see a reason why they *shouldn't* be here if they have a programming element to it.  For example, you pick on FPGA in your example but [there's a whole SDK dedicated to it provided by Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/programmable.html) and one could have programming questions about it.  Especially if you're working on a new core for your [Analogue Pocket](https://www.analogue.co/developer).

I could see similar arguments for VHDL and Verilog as well; if there's a programming question component to them, I don't see why they would suddenly be off-topic here.  They could *also* be on-topic somewhere else, but that doesn't mean that they're retroactively *off-topic* here unless the question wasn't about the programming aspect of it.

Comment: So you say if the question has a programming aspect - leave it. If it is purely electronic design related - vote for moving it to EE site. Did I understand you right?

Comment: @vvv444: Yes, that's the spirit of what I was going for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have specific knowledge of, or even an opinion on, VHDL, Verilog, or FPGA, but generally should questions that are "about" electronic design electronics, yes...

However, "questions about software design and development" and "electronic design related questions" are not classifiers of the content of the question. They are classifiers of the desired outcome (answers, help, and knowledge of people reading) of asking the question; IMO, of course.

I think it is a question of if I ask a question about [IEEE 802.3af](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Two-_and_four-pair_Ethernet) and I'm asking the question, because I want to know about [Amperage for Sony SNC-VB630 Camera](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/136649) vs. if I ask a question about IEEE 802.3af, because I want to know [How does the Linux kernel detect Power over Ethernet (PoE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10006967/3296422), because one of those definitely doesn't belong on *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)* and one of them definitely doesn't belong on SO.

The tag IEEE 802.3 can definitely coexist though. I can only imagine the same applies to any HDL if the underlying hardware is also programmed—as opposed to a nut, which is hardware that isn't programmed.

Comment: Something appears to be missing near *"but generally"*.